# having problems including winbase.h

Tags: c++, windows64

I'm building a program on Visual Studio 2017 and I need Winbase.h in order to write INI files.  However when I try to debug the program I'm getting a bunch of errors related to Winbase.h, even though I haven't changed anything in that file.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C3646: 'nLength': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(48): error C3646: 'lpSecurityDescriptor': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(48): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(49): error C3646: 'bInheritHandle': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(49): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(53): error C3646: 'Internal': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(54): error C3646: 'InternalHigh': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\minwinbase.h(54): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Looking at minwinbase.h itself my best guess is that it's code for 32-bit windows and I'm using 64-bit.  If I'm right, is there any alternative to using winbase.h for 64-bit platforms?

Comment: Those errors are *build* errors, which means there's something wrong with the code you attempt to *build* (which have to be done before debugging). And you should really never include any Windows system except `windows.h`.